# Xaml textblock display items in the next line

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have this textblock

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind item}" Width="100" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontSize="15" />
```

I would like if the text exceed the width of the textblock to break o the next line
How do i achieve this that is

```
this my text this is the newline
of the text
```

Currently if the text surpass the width of 100 they are cut off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `TextWrapping="Wrap"` for your `TextBlock`

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind item}" Width="100" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontSize="15" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

For more info: [TextBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock#examples), [TextWrapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.TextWrapping)